# Python - Use two zipped lists multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have the following zip: `a = zip(list_a, list_b)`.
It was always my understanding that once I zipped `a`, it would stay zipped. Such that the following would work:

```
for iteration in range(100):
   for i, j in a:
      # do something
```

But I noticed that on the second iteration `a` was empty. First of all, is my understanding of `zip` correct, and secondly, is there a simple single line alternative that would fit in this situation?

Comment: Zip is a generator. Save it to a list if you want to keep it.

Comment: @CJR: Pedantic nitpick: It's an iterator, not a generator (Python generators are special user-defined functions involving the `yield` keyword, or the product of generator expressions). But yes, >90% of the time, the distinction is meaningless; you can iterate them once, then they're used up.

Comment: Do you want to store the zipped pairs, or do you want to be able to run your iterator more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` returns an iterator; it produces each pair once, then it's done. So the solution is usually to just inline the `zip` in the loop so it's recreated each time:

```
for iteration in range(100):
   for i, j in zip(list_a, list_b):
      # do something
```

or if that doesn't work for some reason, just `list`-ify the `zip` iterator up front so it's reusable:

```
a = list(zip(list_a, list_b))
```

and then use your original looping code.